# Equally divide a field into 2

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I equally divide the 'col' field of table 't2' with a,b,c,d as records into 2 equal fields : Col1 (a,b) & Col2 (c,d)?

Table:t2

```
Col
A 
B
C
D
```

---

Output:

```
Col1 Col2
 A     C
 B     D
```

this is what i have tried:

```
SELECT a.col1, "" as col2
FROM (SELECT  Top 50 Percent Col as Col1 From t2 order by Col ASc) as a

Union all

SELECT "", b.col1
FROM (SELECT  top 50 Percent Col as Col1 From t2 order by Col Desc) as b
```

Output from above:

```
col1    col2
a   
b   
         d
         c
```

I'm only able to reach so far (in Ms access). Any help is much appreciated.

Create table 't2'

```
Create Table t2(Col  Char)
```

Insert Values

```
INSERT INTO t2 ([Col]) VALUES ("a")
INSERT INTO t2 ([Col]) VALUES ("b")
INSERT INTO t2 ([Col]) VALUES ("c")
INSERT INTO t2 ([Col]) VALUES ("d")
```

Comment: Funky question. Maybe a Pivot / Crosstab query would be the best way. Out of curiosity, is this a real-world-problem?

Comment: @Andre No, practice question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a crosstab if you have a sequential ID:

```
TRANSFORM 
    First(T.Col) AS Col
SELECT 
    ([ID]+1)\2 AS DualID
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, [ID] Mod 2 AS ColID, [Col]
    FROM YourTable) AS T
GROUP BY 
    ([ID]+1)\2
PIVOT 
    T.ColID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A1.COL1 &  "-" & B1.COL1 AS PAIRS
FROM 
(SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT A.Col AS COL1 FROM t2 AS A ORDER BY A.Col ASC) AS A1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT B.Col AS COL1 FROM t2 AS B ORDER BY B.Col DESC) AS B1 
ON A1.COL1 <> B1.COL1
WHERE  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2 AS C WHERE C.Col < A1.COL1) = (SELECT 
COUNT(*) FROM t2 AS D WHERE D.Col > B1.COL1)
```